# How to calculate derivative of an array using finite difference?

Tags: python, pandas

I have created a synthetic data using this code-

```
# x variable
x_value = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,1000)
# y variable
for i in x_value:    
    y_value = np.sin(x_value)
# create a dataframe with the x and y values
data = pd.DataFrame({'x':x_value, 'y':y_value})
```

I would like to create a third column for derivative of x ( cos(x_value)) calculated manually using finite difference method- where for value of 1st row I have to use forward difference method, last row- backward difference and for the rest use central difference.
My code is like this -

```
# differnce for xvalue, delta_x
data['delta_x']= data['x'].diff(1) # resukts in 0.006289 
# create an empty column
data['deriv'] = ''

# function for Central difference for row 2 to 2nd last row
for i in range(1,len(data)-1):
    data['deriv'][i] = (data['y'][i+1]-data['y'][i-1])/(2*0.006289)
# for the 1st row - forward difference
data['deriv'][0] = (data['y'][1]-data['y'][0])/0.006289
# for the last row - backward difference
data['deriv'].iloc[-1] =  (data['y'].iloc[-1]-data['y'].iloc[-2])/0.006289
```

I am getting the desired output ( true derivate and calculated derivatives match) but I am getting this warning for the difference methods- SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
Also, I am looking for an efficient way to write this code.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

#### Explanation

Do not use the `iloc` method to assign the value, please use the `at` method.
Like this `data['deriv'].at[-1] = (data['y'].iloc[-1]-data['y'].iloc[-2])/0.006289`

reference [pandas.DataFrame.at](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html)

#### Modified code

```
# differnce for xvalue, delta_x
data['delta_x']= data['x'].diff(1) # resukts in 0.006289 
# create an empty column
data['deriv'] = ''

# function for Central difference for row 2 to 2nd last row
for i in range(1,len(data)-1):
    data['deriv'].at[i] = (data['y'][i+1]-data['y'][i-1])/(2*0.006289)
# for the 1st row - forward difference
data['deriv'].at[0] = (data['y'][1]-data['y'][0])/0.006289
# for the last row - backward difference
data['deriv'].at[-1] =  (data['y'].iloc[-1]-data['y'].iloc[-2])/0.006289
```

#### Result

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tao-Lung. This method worked very well for the first row, but when I run ```data['deriv'].at[-1] = (data['y'].iloc[-1]-data['y'].iloc[-2])/0.006289 ``` I get an additional row with index -1. If I use the real indexing for the last two rows i.e. 999 and 998 then it works. Is there another way to access the last row other than [-1]?

Comment: I tried your code and didn't encounter the same problem.

Comment: Thanks Tao-Lung for modifying the code and sharing it with me. As you can see in the output there's no value for 'deriv' column for last row(index 999). When I do the same as you did I get  an additional row( at the end) with index -1. I would like to insert an image of the output but I don't know how to insert image - I am new to this. Thanks again for helping me with this. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are curious about why you are getting the error you can read more about [returning a view vs copy of a numpy array](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy).

To improve your code as a whole, I would recommend trying to utilize numpy's vector operations rather than using for loops.

An example would be for calculating your y_value. I would love to point out that you have a for loop in which you are repeatedly reassigning

```
y_value = np.sin(x_value)
```

without ever using the variable i. I would remove the for loop entirely to save time and speed up the work.